# How would I position my navigation menu bars on the right?

Tags: html, css

I am building my first website and I would like to place my navigation menu on the right but I can't seem to figure it out.
In my opinion the navigation menu bars being on the left can be irritating to the user.
Your help would be appreciated.

CSS

```
nav .fa-solid{
  display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 500px){
  .nav-links ul li{
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-links{
    position: absolute;
    background: #f44336;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  nav .fa-solid{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
  <body>
    <section class="header">
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MUSIC</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ART</a></li>
            <li><a href="">GAMES</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MERCH</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out and `display:flex` to `nav` and remove `position:absolute` as it just forces the things to happen. You can use `flex` and I guess that's a better approach. You can change the style as per the size of the screen and placing it with `flex` will help you further in your design.

```css
nav{
 display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

nav .fa-solid{
  display: none;
 
}
@media(max-width: 500px){


  .nav-links ul li{
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-links{
    background: #f44336;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  nav .fa-solid{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
 <nav>
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MUSIC</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ART</a></li>
            <li><a href="">GAMES</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MERCH</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
      </nav>
```

Comment: @swishswisher if it worked and sorted out your problem then marking it right or upvoting it will really help new developers...

Comment: I have been told I need atleast 15 reputation before I can upvote

Answer (score 0):

well you can try something like this

```
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_topnav_right
```

code:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: #04AA6D;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .topnav-right {
      float: right;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="topnav">
            <div class="topnav-right">
            <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#news">News</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          
            <a href="#search">Search</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    
    <div style="padding-left:16px">
      <h2>Top Navigation with Right Aligned Links</h2>
      <p>Some content..</p>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: should I change the class from ```.nav``` to ```.topnav``` ?

Comment: well its about try and test. btw use **Float** in class style